# DevOps Pipeline changing Timeformat when sending variable values as JSON Body to Deploy Azure Resources with Terraform

Tags: json, azure, terraform, devops, azure-deployment

My Terraform Deployment for Azure Resources contains a Budget, which requires a start and end date. When I'm sending my JSON Body/variable value from my Logic App over an http Post, DevOps changes the  timeformat of my string values. Terraform requires a specific timeformat which is RFC 3339. Whenever I'm sending my data to DevOps, it gets changed to another standard which isn't valid.

Error from Pipeline:

```
│ Error: expected "time_period.0.end_date" to be a valid RFC3339 date, got "06/01/2022 11:53:27": parsing time "06/01/2022 11:53:27" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "1/2022 11:53:27" as "2006"
│ 
│   with azurerm_consumption_budget_resource_group.management,
│   on costmanagement.tf line 33, in resource "azurerm_consumption_budget_resource_group" "management":
│   33:     end_date   = var.end_date
│ 
╵
##[error]Terraform command 'plan' failed with exit code '1'.
##[error]╷
│ Error: expected "time_period.0.end_date" to be a valid RFC3339 date, got "06/01/2022 11:53:27": parsing time "06/01/2022 11:53:27" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "1/2022 11:53:27" as "2006"
│ 
│   with azurerm_consumption_budget_resource_group.management,
│   on costmanagement.tf line 33, in resource "azurerm_consumption_budget_resource_group" "management":
│   33:     end_date   = var.end_date
```

Body I'm sending:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "end_date": {
      "isSecret:": false,
      "value": "2022-07-31T11:53:23.000Z"
    },
    "start_date": {
      "isSecret:": false,
      "value": "2022-06-01T11:53:27.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I prevent that it gets changed during the deployment?

Comment: What is the definition for the `var.end_date` and what is passed to that variable?

Comment: the value you which you can see in the body is passed to that variable
"variables": {
    "end_date": {
      "isSecret:": false,
      "value": "2022-07-31T11:53:23.000Z"

Comment: Try with `var.end_date["value"]`.

Comment: Always happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that needs to be changes is to reference one (out of two keys) in the JSON type variable `end_date`:

```
end_date = var.end_date["value"]
```

This way only the key with name `value` will be referenced. Similarly, if you needed to access the value for the `isSecret` key (or any other key added to the variable in the future), you would use:

```
someargument = var.end_date["isSecret"] # or var.end_date["<key-name>"]
```

More information about accessing values of `map` variables can be found in [1].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/type-constraints#map